# std::clamp - detect if function return value is binded to const T&

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17, clamp

It is better not to bind `std::clamp` return value to const ref, if one of its `min` or `max` parameters are rvalues.

Typical realization of `std::clamp` (very simplified):

```
template <class T>
constexpr const T& clamp(const T& value, const T& min, const T& max)
{
    return value < min ? min : max < value ? max : value;
}
```

And as already stated in [cppreference for std::clamp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) there is a dangerous situation when someone write:

```
int n = -1;
const int& r = std::clamp(n, 0, 255);
// r is dangling
```

Is there any way for compile-time-detect these cases?

Comment: Is there any way to catch this with either **AddressSanitizer** or **UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer**? I've tried both and unfortunately can't seem to get them to complain.

Comment: If it was not in `std`, you might add an deleted overload like `template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value || std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>::value || std::is_rvalue_reference<V&&>::value>
clamp(T&& value, U&& min, V&& max) = delete;`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, but such a way you will delete a possibility to use `int r = std::clamp(n, 0, 255);`

Comment: This looks like a defect in the standard library.

Comment: @vladon: You cannot check function argument according of the usage of the returned value. in both cases, it is `std::clamp(n, 0, 255);`.

Comment: Why was this template function designed to return a reference in the first place?

Comment: @A.S.H To avoid copy of big objects passed to it.

Comment: @vladon I guess so, but most if not all of its typical use-cases is with numbers. Not omparing and clamping big objects....

Comment: @vladon But they could still have overloaded for r-values, puzzles me..

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to write your own clamp function, you can detect this and do something about it.

For example, suppose you want the clamp function to return by value if that is the only way to ensure that we don't get a dangling reference:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class A, class B, class C>
constexpr std::conditional_t<
    std::is_lvalue_reference<A &&>::value && std::is_lvalue_reference<B &&>::value && std::is_lvalue_reference<C &&>::value,
    std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::common_type_t<A, B, C>>,
    std::common_type_t<A, B, C>
> clamp(A && value, B && min, C && max)
{            
    return value < min ? min : max < value ? max : value;
}
```

This would make `clamp(n, 0, 255)` effectively have the signature `int clamp(int&, int&&, int&&)`; you'd only get `int & clamp(int&, int&, int&)` if all 3 inputs are lvalue references. Making the returned reference `const` is trivial if you so desire.

You could also have the function fail to compile if they weren't all lvalue references:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class A, class B, class C>
constexpr std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::common_type_t<A, B, C>>
    clamp(A && value, B && min, C && max)
{
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference<A &&>::value && std::is_lvalue_reference<B &&>::value && std::is_lvalue_reference<C &&>::value, "");

    return value < min ? min : max < value ? max : value;
}
```

Comment: Makes me wonder why the hell (sorry for the language) didn't implement std::clamp this way. At least they could have prevented rvalues